# why $ is passed as argument to callback($) in the Zepto library where they define DOMContentLoaded event listener?

Tags: javascript, zepto

I'm browsing through the Zepto source code and there is this little function 
here: [gitHub - Zepto.js](https://github.com/madrobby/zepto/blob/master/src/zepto.js)

```
ready: function(callback){
      if (readyRE.test(document.readyState)) callback($)
      else document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ callback($) }, false)
      return this
    }
```

I don't understand why $ is passed as argument to the callback??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's so that there's a convenient, local reference to the library that can be called whatever you want it to. So, for example, jQuery (which does the same thing) may not be called `$`, but you can call it that without an extra function by doing:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Your jQuery code here, which uses $ as an alias for jQuery
});
```

Comment: I think I still don't get the point. Do you mean that you are passing jQuery or Zepto to the callback so there I can use the framework?

Comment: @JackNova: Yup - but you can call it anything you want is the point.

Comment: but if I called $.fn.ready() this means I have a reference to $ so why you have to pass the reference to the callback again?

Comment: @JackNova: Zepto doesn't know you called it from `$.fn.ready`. Maybe you made the mistake of including another library that uses the same name, like Prototype, which overwrote `$`. So, you used `Zepto.fn.ready` instead. It lets you bring back `$`, but only for the scope of that code, so it doesn't interfere with anything else that uses Prototype. (I've been in this unfortunate situation before, too.)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the bottom of the [repository on gitHub](https://github.com/madrobby/zepto/blob/master/src/zepto.js), you'll see:

```
// If `$` is not yet defined, point it to `Zepto`
window.Zepto = Zepto
'$' in window || (window.$ = Zepto)
```

It's basically giving you a shorthand for Zepto.